# linkedin : Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'.

When I am login with linkedin then I am getting this error

> Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.

This is my settings:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Api key and value, set properly?

Comment: title says `twitter`?

Comment: Redirect URL should probably be `http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback` - this is how OmniAuth strategies work. Then you should open up your site as `http://localhost:3000` and try to authenticate.

Comment: @bodrovis bro saved my time :). But incase of facebook gem 'omniauth-facebook' redirect_uri http://localhost:3000 is working fine.

Comment: [LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 issue – Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.](https://naveengopisetty.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/linkedin-oauth-2-0-issue-invalid-redirect_uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the-api-key/) Please see if this helps.

Comment: Solution in my case: press update after adding the URLs :)

Comment: hello @Dipak Panchal time to choose an ans ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Went back to LinkedIn developer site (https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer ) to check my setting again. Everything matches API Key, Secret Key and OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs.

Searched web looking for some clues. Couldn’t find a one.
  **Crazy issue**:

> *Then I saw that in the URL Owin was appending some extra string to the redirect_uri “signin-linkedin”*.
>  When I decoded the URL I saw this http://localhost:54307/signin-linkedin . 
> I took this URL and placed it in the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs field in the LinkedIn developer site.

This link is helpful for me 
https://naveengopisetty.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/linkedin-oauth-2-0-issue-invalid-redirect_uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the-api-key/

Comment: Adding "signin-linkedin" at the end of the uri like this: http://www.example.com/signin-linkedin  worked for me!

Comment: i resolved that error, but can you tell me how to open that login screen inside browser instead of opening in network tab? i'm facing very strange problem, screen is being opening in network tab instead of opening in browser

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can just look in url that you are getting that error message on.

eg. if you are using python's social auth the url would look like this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress&state=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://example.com.au/sa/complete/linkedin-oauth2/&response_type=code&client_id=YYYYYYY
```

so you would use this part of the above url for the redirect url

```
http://example.com/sa/complete/linkedin-oauth2/
```

Answer (score 7):

please check your redirect_url. for my case I see like this.

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=77k93y0w31zaey&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1729%2Fsignin-linkedin&scope=r_basicprofile%2Cr_emailaddress&state=nhAC-nR-CgEwO3XS2ezANhuPBMz-IUmLPJYgGHlZvZ8B1pCfsGBU0PR0dZ5XxE4zbyeI0RLcKByqPLKkgQdqMm4s6DjFYqMCEehYA2iWT9MfioEHjPXGCt2USxUTF0wKBpflCUjG5URVlJa3qI7U3ydFOErZ4Hhnr9SVmKdf1bithYfbOqBx345o8LQLexbddQ687vP6y0szrIyCM6FHip1tCpOY3Hgg5FJQEFH1mCJ_yLunD5vDUN4VVfkQbcjk

for this I add the url for OAuth 2.0 Authorized Redirect URLs:

http://localhost:1729/signin-linkedin

where http://localhost:1729 =base url and
signin-linkedin = the string which add after base url

Answer (score 2):

One more solution is to just verify the client_id you've been using the whole time..because with every update in the list of redirect_uri, the client_id gets updated.

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Whenever you change redirect_uri clientid changes so don't forget to copy new client id. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning when one uses libraries to handle oauth: some libraries fail to care about the protocol that is used (or at least require further parametrization). Eg, I gave Linkedin https://example/callback as oauth2 url, but the library sent the request with http://example/callback as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this when trying to authorise from a zurb Reveal modal popup.  In my case, the issue was the URL for the page that was being displayed in the popup was not in my OAuth2 Redirect URLs list on the LinkedIn developer site.

That was easy to miss because the page URL from the page in the modal is not the URL that was currently showing in the browser's address bar.  Once I added the URL for the page being shown in the pop up it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours i finally get to the solution. You got an error no issues just check the url and find redirect_uri. Copy and Paste it's value it in your linkedin dev account oauth2 redirect field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add both with and without trailing '/' as redirect url.

```
http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2
http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/
```