# Linkedin authentication using auth0 Firebase and Ionic

Tags: oauth, firebase, ionic-framework, linkedin-api, auth0

I am using auth0.com to create a seed project with Firebase and Ionic (under **Apps / APIs**).

However, I ran into this issue `Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key`. I did the following research:

[linkedin : Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570194/linkedin-invalid-redirect-uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the)
(Tried to use `http://localhost:8100/auth/linkedin/callback` in `OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs` and not working)

https://naveengopisetty.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/linkedin-oauth-2-0-issue-invalid-redirect_uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the-api-key/ (`http://localhost:8100/signin-linkedin` not working)

https://www.drupal.org/node/2357091 (`http://localhost:8100/linkedin/company/token` is not working as well)

Regardless of what I changed in Linkedin app, the login popup url always has `redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyproject.auth0.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback`

That means for some reason my redirect url didn't get change and somehow auth0 forced a "wrong" url in it?

Anyone has an idea how to fix this? Or is it auth0.com bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using LinkedIn, you should follow the instructions on how to configure as an email provider from [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/linkedin-clientid)

The important part is that you must set `https://{accountName}.auth0.com/login/callback` as the Callback URL in the LinkedIn app you create. Did you do that?

Does this help?

Thanks!