# Invalid localhost origin when use Linkedin javascript authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, jwt, auth0

Just a follow-up from this question:

[Linkedin authentication using auth0 Firebase and Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790683/linkedin-authentication-using-auth0-firebase-and-ionic/29801994)

I am trying a combination of auth0, Firebase, Ionic, Linkedin.

I got this error after the popup appears and I clicked login:

```
There was an error logging in Error: error: invalid origin: http://localhost:8100 {stack: (...), message: "error: invalid origin: http://localhost:8100"}
```

[image]

Although I already had localhost in the app form:

[image]

The strange part is when I click refresh in the browser, it said I was authenticated last time and showed my email.

Anyone has a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add that origin (localhost:8001) to the list of Allowed CORS origins in your Auth0 dashboard.

Please check this: http://d.pr/i/11zQx

Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to switch on "Use Auth0 instead of the IdP to do Single Sign On"?