# Django The redirect_uri does not match the registered value for linkedin signup

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I am trying to add linkedin signup to my website but I am getting this error:

**"Bummer, something went wrong.The redirect_uri does not match the registered value"** I am using django [social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html).

I put this redirect url in linkedin OAuth 2.0 settings:

https://www.example.com/complete/linkedin-oauth2/

I also found few question on stackoverfolow and followed but didn't work.
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570194/linkedin-invalid-redirect-uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the)

Comment: What is the value of redirect_uri in the query/GET parameters of the URL that returns the error? Does it match the setting match exactly, including the protocol (it's https not http)?

Comment: Do I need to be add https in my settings.py ???if yes then how? My website already using https protocol which installed on my server

Comment: Is your app being served behind a webserver like nginx? You may need to configure some settings to get Django to detect https if so

Comment: I added `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in mt settings.py but still now same error

Comment: You need to set `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` and `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
` in your settings so that Django picks up the correct host and protocol from your webserver

Comment: added your code and still now same problem. I also have facebook,twitter and gitub login and they don't have any issue  even they were working with out added ssl code in my settings.py. I am not understanding why it's not working  for linkedin

Comment: I am  pretty sure this might be causing for redirect url but don't know what will be right redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved now.

As Iain Shelvington mentioned. I added following code in my settings.py which will enforce all request to https

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

The most important part the Authorized redirect URLs for your app should be this in your OAuth 2.0 settings:

https://example.com/complete/linkedin-oauth2/

Instead of example.com put your own domain

If you are using any cdn then like cloudflare then go to your ssl settings and turned on https redirect.